# Regex to search for two consecutive lines if the second doesn't start with a given word

Tags: regex

I am trying (in *Eclipse*, I don't know if the syntax is different there) to write a regex that will select everything from **'service'** up to the next two **';'**, but skipping the search if between the two **';'** there is the word **'assert'**.

This means that in the following example, I would like to select the text **'service.updateBasket.........test();'** and not the text **'service.createBasket.........asserThat.....;'**

```
BasketBean updateBasketRepsonse =
   service.updateBasket(login.getSessionId(),
                        Identity.valueOf(createdbasketBean.getGeneralID()),
                        basketSaveRequestBean);

test();

Response createBasketResponse = service.createBasket(login.getSessionId(),
                                                     basketSaveRequestBean);

assertThat(createBasketResponse).hasStatus(Status.CREATED);
```

So far I've written the regex `service\.(.*\R)*?.*;`, which finds the text I want till the first **';'**. But I am having problem in handling the search till the next **';'**.

For example `service\.(.*\R)*?.*;\R.*;` sometimes goes up to the third **';'** (if there is an empty line after the first **';'**)... and I don't understand why.

Especially, I can't seem to find a way to skip the search if the line after the first **';'** starts with **'assertThat'** - that would be my final goal.

Note that the lines I am searching for are CONSECUTIVE, i.e. that the search only has to consider lines where the first **';'** is followed by a line with text... as mentioned above, I am having troubles with that too :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
service(?![^;]*;[^;]*assert[^;]*;)[^;]*;[^;]*;
```

See **[this demo](http://regexr.com?37dnq)**.

---

#### EDIT:

To prevent empty lines to be a part of match, use more complex pattern

```
service(?!(?:[^;\n\r]|[\n\r](?![\n\r]))*;(?:[^;\n\r]|[\n\r](?![\n\r]))*assert(?:[^;\n\r]|[\n\r](?![\n\r]))*;)(?:[^;\n\r]|[\n\r](?![\n\r]))*;(?:[^;\n\r]|[\n\r](?![\n\r]))*;
```

See **[this demo](http://regexr.com?37dp4)**.

Comment: OK it kind of works although it also matches text like:
service = client.proxy(IBasketService.class); [NEW_LINE HERE] 
[NEW_LINE HERE] //Create basket [NEW_LINE HERE] BasketSaveRequestBean basketSaveRequestBean1 = new BasketSaveRequestBean();
I solved this by searching for "service\." although I am not sure if it really handles the new liens or if I just got lucky

Comment: @PLB - And WHY that should not match..?

Comment: Well I am trying to get two consecutive lines with text, while this syntax also takes empty lines...

Comment: @PLB - You example in the question takes 4 lines and you want it to be matched, so it is confusing... You want to prevent empty line to be a part of match? If so, what is empty line for you - even with white spaces in it, or nothing between new-line characters..? You need to be more clear!

Comment: well I am confused too, now ;) and probably there was a flaw in my reasoning. Here's the thing: I can call several different methods on the "service" object, and due to the syntax formatter those can be spread on several lines. after each call, I must use an assertion to check that I got the correct result. Sometimes this assertion is already there (in the line JUST BELOW the end of the call), sometimes not. So I was trying to get each call that is NOT directly followed by an assertion (on the next consecutive line. cause I might have different assertions but there's always a white line befor)

Answer (score 0):

> > For example `service\.(.*\R)*?.*;\R.*;` sometimes goes up to the third ';' (if there is an empty line after the first ';')... and I don't understand why.

I think that you are missing only a small part off of the end of your expression
try

```
service\.(.*\R)*?.*;\R.*?;
```

The final `?` makes the last part of the expression lazy which means that it should only go up to the second `;`